# A result was returned when none was expected. SpringBoot/Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to select only last row in my table and return this int in my variable. 
This is my method in my Repository :

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value="SELECT category_id FROM category ORDER BY category_id DESC LIMIT 1\r\n", nativeQuery = true)
int  selectLastRecord();
```

And when I call method with this code:

```
int categoryId = this.categoryRepository.selectLastRecord();
```

I have the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
```

Comment: Remove the Modifying annotation. It must be used for queries that **modify** the database, i.e. insert, update or delete.

Comment: Just Remove `@Modifying`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queries that require a `@Modifying` annotation include INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and DDL statements.

Adding `@Modifying` annotation indicates the query is not for a SELECT query.

So remove `@Modifying`.

Reference [Modifying](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html)